# Como retornar valor real de uma coluna no datatables jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-datatables

Estou alimentando minha tabela por ajax e customizando o retorno.
Na coluna `status`( 0 ou 1 ) eu usei o `"fnRender"` para retornar um label de **ativo** ou **inativo** de acordo com o valor, porém preciso utilizar esta mesma validação para mostrar o botão **Desativar** ou **Ativar** e quando chego neste passo o `"fnRender"` sobrescreveu o valor real de `status` para `"<span class='label label-success'>Ativo</span>"`( ou Inativo ) e a minha validação para `"mData":"id"` que é `if(parseInt(oObj.aData['status']) == 1)` acaba caindo sempre no else.

**Possível solução**

```
if(oObj.aData['status'] == "<span class='label label-success'>Ativo</span>")
```

O problema é que eu não queria realizar esta validação pela string, parece de alguma forma que isso não está certo.

**Javascript:**

```
var tabela = $('#dynamic-table');

    tabela.dataTable( {
        "aaSorting": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "minhaURL",
        "aoColumns": [{
            "mData":"nome"
          },
          {
            "mData":"status",
            "bSortable": false,
            "fnRender": function (oObj)                              
            {
                var status;
                if(parseInt(oObj.aData['status']) == 1){
                    status = "<span class='label label-success'>Ativo</span>"; 
                }else{
                    status = "<span class='label label-danger'>Inativo</span>";
                }
                return status;
            }
          },
          { 
            "mData":"id",    
            "bSearchable": false,
            "bSortable": false,
            "fnRender": function (oObj)                              
            {
                var btAtivaDesativa;
                btEditar = "<a href='" + oObj.aData['id'] + "' class='btn btn-primary'>Editar</a>";
                if(parseInt(oObj.aData['status']) == 1){
                    btAtivaDesativa = "<a href='" + oObj.aData['id'] + "' class='btn btn-danger'>Desativar</a>"; 
                }else{
                    btAtivaDesativa = "<a href='" + oObj.aData['id'] + "' class='btn btn-success'>Ativar</a>";
                }
                return btEditar + " " + btAtivaDesativa;
            }
           }
        ] 
    } );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link da resposta no [**SOEN**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22996890/how-to-return-the-column-real-value-in-datatables-jquery/23013660?noredirect=1#23013660)

Basicamente o correto é usar o `"mRender"` não alterando o valor real na variável quando acesso pela var `full`:

```
{
  "mData": 1,
  "bSortable": false,
  "mRender": function(data, type, full) {
     if (full['status'] == '1') {
       return '<a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" >Edit</a>';
     }         
     return '';
   }
}
```

Comment: explica direito Ale! rss kkkk